# synchronize and merge messaging/data flow

Tags: java, concurrency, merge, messaging, sensors

It is about very common sensor data processing problem.

To synchronize and merge sensor data from different sources, I would like to implement it in Java without too complicated 3rd libs or framework.

Say, I define an object (O) which consists of, for example, 4 attributes (A1,..A4). The 4 attributes come from different data channels, e.g. socket channel.

The 4 attributes arrive generally in a rate of 1.0 ~ 2.0 Hz and their arrivals are independent from each other.
Once there are 4 attributes (A1, ..A4) coming *at the same time* (within a small time window, e.g. 100ms), then I construct a new object (O) from those 4 attributes.

a descriptive scenario is as follows.
the arrival time point of A1 ~ A4 is marked with *.

Objects O1 ~ U3 are constructed on the time point of t1, t2 and t3 respectively.
Some attributes arrives between t2 and t3, but are not complete for constructing an Object, therefore they 
would be dropped and ignored.

```
  A1     *          *         *         *
  A2      *           *         *        *
  A3     *            *                  * 
  A4      *            *       *         * 
  --------|------------|-----------------|----------> time
          t1           t2                t3
          O1           O2                O3
```

some requirements:

1. identify the time point **a.s.a.p.** to construct a object from the last incoming 4 attributes.
2. FIFO, O1 must be constructed before O2, and so on.
3. less locking in Java
4. drop data eventually if they are not complete to construct a object.

Some quick idea on implementation are:

- store any incoming attributes in a FIFO queue of time-discrete buckets (each bucket contains 4 different attributes).
- run an endless thread concurrently to check the FIFO queue (from the head of the queue) if any  bucket is already filled with 4 different attributes. If yes, then construct an object and remove the bucket from the queue. If a bucket is not complete filled within a specific time window, it will be dropped.

any suggestion and correction is welcome!

Comment: Just to make sure I'm clear about the dropping of data, you're saying that, for example, A1 should be dropped if A2-A4 are not popoulated within ~100 ms of each other? So if A1 arrives and then nothing happens for 150 ms, then A2, A3 and A4 arrive within about 50ms, the Object won't be created because there is no valid A1. Provided a new A1 arrives within 100ms of the earliest out of A2, A3, and A4, an Object can be created, and if not, A2, A3 and A4 are dropped.

Comment: Should the data arrive at certain fixed rate, so that you know around what time they should arrive?

Comment: Thinking about it more, another way of what you're describing is a sliding window of 100ms long, and if data arrives for all four points in that window, you can create an object.

Comment: @Kaj: the sensors which produce the data (attributes here) may not be  reliable.

Comment: @elgcom. You can in that case take a look at my example. I think it does what you want, and can handle configurable amount of censors.

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to solve your problem, but it might point you in the right direction.

I would use Google Guava's [MapMaker](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) for a first attempt:

```
ConcurrentMap<Key, Bucket> graphs = new MapMaker()
                                   .expireAfterAccess(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECOND)
                                   .makeComputingMap(new Function<Key, Bucket>() {
                                                     public Bucket apply(Key key) {
                                                         return new Bucket(key);
                                                     }
                                    });
```

This would create a map whose entries would disappear if they had not been accessed for 100 ms, and creates a new bucket when it is asked for.

What I can't work out is exactly what the Key would be :S What you're really after is the same kind of functionality in the form of a queue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another crazy idea:

use one single `LinkedBlockingQueue` to write values to from all sensors A1-A4

assign this queue to `AtomicReference` variable

create a timer task which will switch this queue with a new one at specified intervals (100ms)

fetch all data from the old queue and see if you have all data A1-A4

if yes, then create the object, otherwise drop everything

Comment: I think the problem with that is that you may lose data - A1 could arrive at the end of the lifetime of the first queue, while the others could arrive at the beginning of the lifetime of the next queue. Thus the four data points have arrived within the time limit, but the object won't be created because they don't share the same queue.

Comment: yeah, that's true.. will think something else :)

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it - it's just pseudocode though, you'll need to write it yourself :)

```
class SlidingWindow {
    AtomicReference<Object> a1;
    AtomicReference<Object> a2;
    AtomicReference<Object> a3;
    AtomicReference<Object> a4;

    Queue<Long> arrivalTimes = new Queue(4);

    public Bucket setA1(Object data) {
        a1.set(data);
        now = System.currentTimeInMillis()
        long oldestArrivalTime = arrivalTimes.pop();
        arrivalTimes.push(now);
        if (now - oldestArrivalTime < 100) {
            return buildBucket();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Bucket setA2(Object data) { ...

    ...

    private Bucket buildBucket() {
        Bucket b = new Bucket(a1, a2, a3, a4);
        a1.clear();
        a2.clear();
        a3.clear();
        a4.clear();
        return b;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, the get operation is blocking till data has arrived, the add operation is not blocking. The get operation could be optimized a bit so that you keep candidates in a paralell structure so that you don't need to iterate over all candidates when filtering out old items. Iterating over 4 items should however be fast enough.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class Filter<V> {

    private static final long MAX_AGE_IN_MS = 100;

    private final int numberOfSources;

    private final LinkedBlockingQueue<Item> values = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Item>();

    public Filter(int numberOfSources) {
        this.numberOfSources = numberOfSources;
    }

    public void add(String source, V data) {
        values.add(new Item(source, data));
    }

    public void get() throws InterruptedException {
        HashMap<String, Item> result = new HashMap<String, Item>();
        while (true) {
            while (result.size() < numberOfSources) {
                Item i = values.take();
                result.put(i.source, i);
                if (result.size() == numberOfSources) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            //We got candidates from each source now, check if some are too old.
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Iterator<Item> it = result.values().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Item item = it.next();
                if (now - item.creationTime > MAX_AGE_IN_MS) {
                    it.remove();
                }
            }
            if (result.size() == numberOfSources) {
                System.out.println("Got result, create a result object and return the items " + result.values());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private class Item {
        final String source;
        final V value;
        final long creationTime;

        public Item(String source, V value) {
            this.source = source;
            this.value = value;
            this.creationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.valueOf(value);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Filter<String> filter = new Filter<String>(4);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    filter.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        filter.add("a0", "va0.1");
        filter.add("a0", "va0.2");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        filter.add("a0", "va0.3");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        filter.add("a1", "va1.1");
        filter.add("a2", "va2.1");
        filter.add("a0", "va0.4");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        filter.add("a3", "va3.1");
        Thread.sleep(10);
        filter.add("a1", "va1.2");
        filter.add("a2", "va2.2");
        filter.add("a0", "va0.5");

    }


}
```